# Executable *.jar in IntellijIdea

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, javafx, executable-jar

I want to export my JavaFX app to executable *.jar file in IntelliJ IDEA. I use [Executable jar](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)

but when I running created *.jar file I get an error : 
'Java Virtual Machine Launcher
A Java Exception has Occured'
Where is my mistake?
Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: the problem is the Java version which you are using. Install the latest version and make sure you are using the latest version, in case if you have multiple versions installed.

Comment: I am using jdk1.7.0_51...

Answer (score 0):

Idea has a special artifact for JavaFX applications, you should use that.

You should also use Java 8 rather than Java 7.

[image]